# How to make sure the shell builtin echo is invoked so that its not visible in process list?

Tags: shell, shell-script, security, ps, echo

Is this going to be visible in the process listing if the below line is executed from a command line or a shell script

```
bash -c "echo $password"
```

or

i just need to do `echo $password` from within bash on a command line or inside bash shell script

is there any test i can do to check such visiblity.
i was just trying this but i wasn't able to see it in the process listing with `ps -ef | grep testscript`

testscript:

```
i=0
while (( i < 100 ))
do
((i=i+1))
sleep 1
echo $$
echo hello
uname
done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just force it to use the builtin:

```
builtin echo foo
```

If `echo` is not a builtin, this will fail.

Comment: Thanks @Chris one doubt..is this going to be valid for linux only ? or will it work inside shells other than bash?

Comment: @munish `builtin` is not POSIX, but is supported in most modern shells (bash, zsh, most implementations of ksh).

Answer (score 4):

The arguments to a builtin will never show up in any `ps` output, because the builtin is not a separate program with its own command line. All modern shells (except some highly stripped-down configurations of BusyBox), including all bash versions, have `echo` built in.

Note that if you're calling `bash -c "echo $password"`, then the password will show up for everyone to see, because it's embedded in the command that you run with `bash`. Calling a shell just to call its `echo` command is pointless, so hopefully you aren't doing that.

It's ok to put the password in an environment variable, if you need to pass it to a different process. Unlike command line arguments, [environment variables are not exposed to other users](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14000/environment-variable-accessibility-in-linux/14009#14009) under Linux and most other unices.